# Computing cellular homology of the sphere using a different CW structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I want to compute cellular homology of the sphere $S^n$ using the CW structure where I have two cells $e^k_1,e^k_2$ for each dimension $0 \leq k \leq n$. Let me define the attaching maps to all be homeomorphisms *that preserve orientation*.

With this definition, when we compute the differential maps in the cellular chain complex, we get:
$$\partial e^k_1 = \partial e^k_2 = e^{k-1}_1 + e^{k-1}_2.$$
The problem with this seems to be that $\partial^2 \neq 0$. Clearly, the problem must lie with defining the attaching maps to preserve orientation but I don't see where I went wrong.

Comment: I think you need $\partial e^k_1 = \partial e^k_2 = e^{k-1}_1 - e^{k-1}_2.$

Comment: Yes, that gives the right answer. However, I am more interested in figuring out why my choice of orientations is wrong.

Comment: You can choose the orientations for each cell. But these orientations determine the coefficients in the boundary maps, and you can't choose those orientations separately.